# Is the Google Cloud Datastore Java API threadsafe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, google-cloud-datastore

Here is there Java example:
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/

Is it advisable to create one static datastore object as shown here:

```
datastore = DatastoreFactory.get().create(DatastoreHelper.getOptionsfromEnv()
          .dataset(datasetId).build());
```

And then reuse it across multiple threads calling methods like:

```
LookupResponse lresp = datastore.lookup(lreq.build());
datastore.commit(creq.build());
```

Or should a new datastore be created on each thread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.google.api.services.datastore.client.Datastore` is thread-safe for regular operations. It's based on `com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory` which is also [thread-safe](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestFactory.java?r=ecc679ef215228d2b8f21491ff574089162b09c5#20).

The only exceptions to this are the `resetRpcCount()` and `getRpcCount()` methods (those will be made thread-safe in a future release). Also, if you are providing an `HttpRequestInitializer` in your `DatastoreOptions` (rare), it must also be thread-safe.

Comment: Awesome! So just to be clear, would it be fine to create one Datastore as a static final for a long running application?

Comment: Yes, this should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be looking at releasing datastore objects once done with the operation,

Get
Perform
Release

Let me give you an example,

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
// do your operations
pm.close();
```

PMF is a singleton class, creating a new datastore for each thread could lead to race conditions in my opinion.

Comment: So you think a new Datastore should be created for each operation?

Comment: Create a singleton class and fetch instance, use and close. This would make sure you don't have multiple handles opened up to your datastore.

Comment: Hm, I hope that's not what is needed as that would be very slow.

Comment: I could be wrong, for my use cases till date i've followed this and it has worked fine. Maybe you should wait for more experienced stackoverflow members to give industry proof solution